# Storing and retrieving Sockets in Redis

Tags: node.js, redis

I am new to Node and Redis, so forgive me if I'm missing something crucial here. I am trying to store a Node.js net.Socket object in Redis, using the node_redis client, so I could reuse a connection made previously on this Socket. 
I am storing the socket as a Value as a part of a "users" set:

```
client.sadd("users", username); //username is a string
client.hmset(username, "ip", socket.remoteAddress, "connection", net.Socket(socket));
```

At a different point, I am retrieving this socket as:

```
    client.smembers("users", function(err, replies) {

            replies.forEach(function(reply,i){
            if(recipient == reply) {       //recipient is the username i've got

                    client.hget(reply, "connection", function(err, obj) {
                    console.log("socket's remoteaddress = " +  net.Socket(obj).remoteAddress);
        net.Socket(obj).write("asdasdasd");
            });

            }
    });
    });
```

But, the:
    net.Socket(obj).remoteAddress); is logged as 'undefined'.
Also, 
     net.Socket(obj).write("asdasdasd"); gives me and error saying:

Error: This socket is closed.

So I guess my question is - can you store Sockets this way in Redis and expect them to work upon retrieval?  Is there a correct / better way to do this?

P.S. I tried retrieving the Socket without the cast to net.Socket and it still didn't do any good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sockets and socket APIs (such as [Berkeley Sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets)) intrinsically handle special system-specific resources for which it just wouldn't make any sense to store or reference on a remote system, or even serialize for that matter.

Although, in reality, sockets are often uniquely identified by [file descriptors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) so you could easily store that small, unique integer in a database for later access; however, that integer would only be meaningful during the active lifetime of that socket within that process instance.  A strategy such as this one will be fraught with challenges, mainly having to do with the transient nature of the socket file descriptor number.

Comment: It does look like it's a shot in the dark. I could use the IP address too, but my clients are hidden behind NATs and I have other issues which are sort of discouraging me to open a new connection to the IP address I am storing.

Answer (score 3):

as @maerics said , redis store only string. so your socket data will be destroyed and will give undefined as answer.

you can store your socket like this.

```
var OBJECT = Object.prototype;
OBJECT.rhash = {};
OBJECT.rset = function(id, object) {
  OBJECT.rhash[id] = object;
  return id;
};
OBJECT.rget = function(id) {
  return OBJECT.rhash[id];
};
```

this will store reference to that object and reuse it again..

```
var id = OBJECT.rset("a123",socket);
var ref = OBJECT.rget("a123");
console.log(ref.remoteAddress);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the IP address, it's on a different hash key (not `connection`, but `ip`). So to get the value you just read from that key:

```
client.hget(reply, "ip", function(err, obj) {
   console.log("socket's remoteaddress = " +  obj);
});
```

Comment: Yes, I'm able to read that just fine, and am using that for something else. But I was hoping to use the connection itself directly.